# Could not connect to the database. Connector returned number: Database sqlsrv_connect failed

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, joomla, mysqli

I am unable to connect Joomla to MSSQL
I keep getting

> Could not connect to the database. Connector returned number: Database
>   sqlsrv_connect failed

Whether I use the MySQLi driver or the drivers I installed (Microsoft SQL Server) 

Seems like driver installation issue ,

I am able to connect to the same box with Mssql Client fine...

Can someone post an explanation on how to install MSSQL drivers for Joomla on PHP from scratch?

 Or send an up to date reference on how to do this?

```
Joomla 3.4
PHP 5.6
IIS 7.5
MSSQL 2008 R2
```

If I switch the driver to: php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll - it will disperser from the "database type" in joomla installer..

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The joomla error that is displayed is misleading and not quite useful.
So first step would be to modify the joomla code to find out the exact error.
Modify the following code in connect() function in your application's root directory

### libraries\joomla\database\driver\sqlsrv.php

From

```
// Attempt to connect to the server.
        if (!($this->connection = @ sqlsrv_connect($this->options['host'], $config)))
        {
            throw new RuntimeException('Database sqlsrv_connect failed');
        }
```

To

```
// Attempt to connect to the server.
        if (!($this->connection = @ sqlsrv_connect($this->options['host'], $config)))
        {
           throw new RuntimeException("Database sqlsrv_connect failed - Error : ".print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
```

This will give you the exact error and guide you with the next steps needed.

Another thing to consider during SQL server installation is to enable the SQL server authentication as Joomla uses SQL server authentication by default.
You can confirm that Joomla uses SQL server authentication by checking in the same function in the same file as mentioned above

```
$config = array(
            'Database' => $this->options['database'],
            'uid' => $this->options['user'],
            'pwd' => $this->options['password'],
            'CharacterSet' => 'UTF-8',
            'ReturnDatesAsStrings' => true);
```

Here is the PHP manual that confirms the same.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

You can enable SQL server authentication either during installation or post installation from the manamgement studio.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this helped debugging the issue

Answer (score 1):

- Download SQLServer 2008 Express, SQLServer 2008 Standard/Enterprise
  editions (R2 or later)
- Download PHP Drivers
- Download SQLSRV20.EXE to a temporary directory
- Run SQLSRV20.EXE
- When prompted, enter the path to the PHP extensions directory
- If you are using some sort of LAMP stack like XAMPP
- Copy php_sqlsrv_52_ts_vc6.dll to php/ext folder

**Make an entry in php.ini as follows**

- Extension=php_sqlsrv_52_ts_vc6.dll

Note:

1. If you need PDO or vc9 versions - please copy the "ts" version
   appropriate for your needs.
2. If you are using IIS with PHP engine installed via FAST-CGI - please
   make the appropriate changes in c:\Program Files\php\php.ini and
   copy the dll to c:\Program Files\php\ext folder

Now - You can install Joomla 2.5 by selecting the SQLServer 2008 from the dropdown list in the step 4 of the installation.

After installation is complete - continue navigation around the administrator/site